# How MySQL query works with and without placeholders (?)?

Tags: node.js

I have two approaches to execute sql query in `node.js` , I want to know difference between these two. Which one is recommended to use `?` and why `??`

### First Approach

```
var userId = 1;
var columns = ['username', 'email'];    
var query = connection.query('SELECT ?? FROM ?? WHERE id = ?', 
  [columns, 'users', userId], function(err, results) 
{   
  // ... 
});
```

### Second Approach

```
var userId = 1;
var query = connection.query('SELECT username,email FROM UserTable WHERE id=?', 
  [userId], function(err, results) 
{   
  // ... 
});
```

Please tell me exact use of these two mechanisms.

Answer (score 6):

The double question mark syntax `??` in the substitution string wraps the substituted parameters in delimiters before sending them to the server. The delimiters are appropriate for table and column names. So your first example, `'SELECT ?? FROM ?? WHERE id = ?'` sends

```sql
SELECT `username`, `email` FROM `users` WHERE id = '1'
```

to the server.

The second one, `'SELECT username,email FROM UserTable WHERE id=?'`, sends

```sql
SELECT username,email FROM UserTable WHERE id='1'
```

Comment: The first approach also allows for you to write code generically enough so you can have 1 select statement but cater for almost anything